# Get postgres to show all TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE columns in UTC

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, timestamp

When I do a `SELECT` statement that outputs a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column, it doesn't include the time zone in the output. It just outputs the date and time without the timezone, after converting it to my local timezone.

I have 2 questions:

- How to get all `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` columns to always display their time zones in the output, rather than the default of omitting it?
- How to get all `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` columns to output with a default time zone of `UTC`? I know there's ways to do this on a per-query basis, but I'd like to do it in every case with needing to modify any queries. So a server setting maybe?

Comment: *When I do a SELECT statement that outputs a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column, it doesn't include the time zone in the output.* -- that is almost certainly caused by your client, PostgreSQL itself prints `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` values in the time zone set by the [TimeZone](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-TIMEZONE) setting -- [f.ex. see](http://rextester.com/WQEP6239)

Comment: It says the default is `GMT`, which is what I want, but that it's being overridden in `postgresql.conf`. But I don't have that file. Sure it's not using the local system timezone by default somewhere? Only thing related I have is `/usr/share/postgresql/postgresql.conf.sample`. So not sure where it's being overridden and how to change it back. It's a newly installed system so it's not like there's old files laying around that might be changing some config somewhere.

Comment: If you follow a the link for more information, it is described that `libpq` based clients use a `PGTZ` environment variable to issue a `SET TIME ZONE` command upon connecting. It is *usually* configured by default installations to use the server's own time zone.

Comment: Just checking, you are aware that `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` doesn't actually store the time zone, right?

Answer (score 5):

for one column:

```
 SELECT colname AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' FROM tablename;
```

for all

```
 SET TIMEZONE TO 'UTC';
```

see also `ALTER` ... `SET` ...

Comment: Does `set timezone to 'utc'` change things only for the session or permanently even for other sessions? I'm looking for something permanent rather than having it to set it every time.

Comment: current session only, need to do alter user to effect future sessions.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-alteruser.html

Comment: What if you are selecting multiple columns and only one of them is a date column.
Who only selects date?

Comment: this only works for timestamp with timezone columns,  if you cast the `date` to  `timestamp with timezone` and then said `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'` you would get the timestamp of the local start of the calendar day (00:00:00) represented in zone UTC.